# JWrapper Build Failed OutOfMemoryError

Tags: jwrapper

I am running this build through the JWrapperApp. When ever I try and build my 86.7Mb .jar file, it gets to the step of adding the .jar file to archive then fails with a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. I have tried only building for one OS at a time, as well as adjusting some other settings but none seem to have an effect.

I have successfully been able to build the sample-app and I know my .jar file is in working order.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try starting your JWrapperApp with more memory by passing the JVM option -Xmx1024m or greater to it. This entails starting the JWrapperApp packager from the commandline/shell using the following command:

```
java -Xmx1024m JWrapperApp.jar
```